# Building with add_custom_target in Android Studio CMake

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I have created some custom target executions in my module's `CMakeLists.txt` which is referenced as per the standard template in the module's `build.gradle` with the following:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt` contains the following commands (I think I've included everything that's relevant here):

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${BUILT_PRODUCT_FILEPATH} # The library built by ${CUSTOM_BUILD_COMMAND}, defined elsewhere
    COMMAND ${CUSTOM_BUILD_COMMAND} --product ${PRODUCT_NAME} ${CUSTOM_BUILD_ARGS}
    DEPENDS ${SOURCE_FILES} ${BUILT_PRODUCT_DEPENDENCIES}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_DIRECTORY}
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_PRODUCT_FILEPATH} # filename of BUILT_PRODUCT_FILEPATH in the CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${BUILT_PRODUCT_FILEPATH} ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
    DEPENDS ${BUILT_PRODUCT_FILEPATH}
)

add_custom_target(
    ${PRODUCT_NAME} ALL  # NOTE: I'm using ALL here - could this be part of the issue?
    DEPENDS ${OUTPUT_PRODUCT_FILEPATH}
)
```

When I run `cmake -G Ninja $MODULE_PATH && cmake --build .` my targets are built and the `.so` libraries land in the APK as expected.

Also if I run `Refresh Linked C++ Projects` in Android studio and navigate to `$MODULE_PATH/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a` and run `ninja` the build works too (as above).

What **doesn't work** is just pressing `Build`, `Make Project`, `Rebuild Project` or anything similar from within Android Studio itself. The native build appears to "complete" successfully in 0s but nothing gets built. The `build/intermediates/cmake` directory doesn't even get created at all.

The question is: Which targets does Android Studio build when making the project? And how do I get it to build my custom targets, as seems to work fine given any other environment?

Comment: Is it possible I need to add an `install()` command for Android Studio to register it the target? I couldn't get `install` to work with custom targets.

Answer (score 1):

I was just running into this too. After some fiddling I think I found the answer. Android Studio does not build the ALL_BUILD target. So simply specifying a target `add_custom_target(<my_target> ALL ...)` doesn't work for AS. I added my custom target as a dependency to my main executable with `add_dependencies(<my_exe> <my_custom_target>)` and that worked fine.

Comment: This almost worked, but it caused cyclic dependency error for me, because of `$<TARGET_FILE:my_exe>` command in `my_custom_target`.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this. In my case, I only wanted to build the custom target, so there was no dependency that I could use to force the build. Turns out, there is a way to specify what targets you want built within gradle. Example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "my_custom_target_name", "any_other_target"
            }
        }
     }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
 }
```

This is the better approach as it can help avoid cyclic dependencies.